# Using Regex in Yahoo pipes to remove random numbers

Tags: regex, rss, yahoo-pipes

I'm new to yahoo pipes, sorry if my question isn't that clear. I'm pulling an RSS Feed into Yahoo Pipes and trying to use Regex to remove/ delete the pattern which consists different random numbers like below.

Search

`all 6 bad eggs&nbsp;&raquo;`

`all 39 bad eggs&nbsp;&raquo;`

`all 693 bad eggs&nbsp;&raquo;`

`all 6999 bad eggs&nbsp;&raquo;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`all \d+ bad eggs?` will remove all instances of (one or more) digits surrounded by "all " and " bad egg" (or "eggs").

Comment: thanks for the reply nathan. Im looking to remove the whole sentence like "all 6 bad eggs", "all 49 bad eggs", "all 369 bad eggs", "all 6789 bad eggs". The pattern i see is all and bad eggs. im trying to use regex to remove the occurence. Thanks again

Comment: OK, that should clarify.